# Trigger setState function in parent from promise.then in child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find a solution to `setState` from a `parent` within `child` `promise`.

The `parent` `component` is

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      transition: false
    };
  }

  handleTransition = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ transition: !state.transition }));
  };

  render() {
    return <Child handleTransition={this.handleTransition} />;
  }
}
```

of which `this.props.handleTransition` is to be triggered from a `child` `component` as

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  onSubmit = event => {
    firebase
      .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        // Trigger this.props.handleTransition here
      })
      ...
```

Where `this.props.handleTransition` is wanting to be triggered with `then` of `onSubmit`

Please let me know if you require more detail? I would prefer not to use a library or package to achieve this but if it makes life easier I may consider. Redux is likely the best option but I would prefer not to unless necessary.

Note: `this.props.handleTransition();` does the job but `esLint` returns an error of `Must use destructuring props assignmenteslint(react/destructuring-assignment)` and I am considering that this method is not the correct method.

Comment: so `this.props.handleTransition()` doesn't work?

Comment: I know react probably changes the playing field ... but having arrow functions in classes never works

Comment: Sorry yes it does but I missed that esLint is returning `Must use destructuring props assignment` and I was looking to see if there was another method. I'll update the answer to include this. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Actually not to worry. I just figured out what the error means. Thank you for your help - feeling dumb for jumping the gun on this question now.

Comment: No such thing as a dumb question - just dumb people (kidding :p )

Comment: ha... thanks. If you wanted to answer the question with your suggestion I can accept it for other trigger happy stack overflow users like myself. If not, I will delete.

Comment: not sure I know what the problem actually was - I perhaps accidentally answered you - nothing wrong with answering your own question though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// --- parent.js

import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { ChildComponent } from './containers/child'

class ParentContainer extends Component {

  handleUpdate = () => {
    // whatever you want to do here
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <ChildComponent onUpdate={this.handleUpdate} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default ParentContainer;

// --- child.js

import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

export class ChildComponent extends Component {

  this.someAsyncFunction = () => {
    fetch('/just/for/example')
    .then(res => 
        // Do whatever you need here, then hit your function on parent by bubbling the request up the chain
        this.props.onUpdate();
      ) 
  }

  render(){
     return (
      // whatever you want to do with this data
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This answers the question perfectly, in my case as per my note I had done this but was presented with an `esLint` error and I was wondering if there was another solution. Turns out that the error was just asking me to add `this.props.onUpdate` to `const { onUpdate } = this.props;` and add as `onUpdate()`. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for being my first answer :D